# Basis in Topology confusion

Tags: general-topology

I came across a lemma in some online notes where it says that, "Given a collection of elements of a basis ($\mathcal{B}$), they are also elements of Topology ($\mathcal{T}$) on $X$. How do we know this. I know we can define open sets in terms of basis. How can we go the other way?

I am using the following definition:

If $X$ is a set, a basis for a topology on $X$ is a collection $\mathcal{B}$ of subsets of $X$ (called basis elements) such that

(1)For each $x∈X$, there is at least one basis element $B$ containing $x$

(2)If $x$ belongs to the intersection of two basis elements $B_1$ and $B_2$, then there is a basis
element $B_3$ containing $x$ such that $B_3⊆B_1∩B_2$.

If $\mathcal{B}$ satisfies these two conditions, then we define the topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by $\mathcal{B}$ as follows: A subset $U$ of $X$ is said to be open in $X$ if for each $x∈U$, there is a basis element B∈$\mathcal{B}$ such that $x∈B$ and $B⊆U$.

Comment: By definition, a basis of the topology consists of open sets.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Is it because $X$ is an open set and elements of $\mathcal{B}$ produce $X$ and thus $\mathcal{B}$ is open as union of open sets is open. But by this definition can't we argue that since $X$ is closed, basis is also closed

Comment: @JamesBond, $\mathcal{B}$ is some special collection of open sets. $\mathcal{B}$ is not open in itself nor is it closet since it's a collection of sets and not a subset of $X$ ! However, the union of all elements in the collection $\mathcal{B}$ is open (this union is in fact $X$) as union of open sets is open.

Comment: @M.G: Please let me know if I am understanding this correctly: The union of any elements in $\mathcal{B}$ will only produce open sets. If thats the case then why do we have the concept of topology. Wouldn't $\mathcal{B}$ get our work done?

Comment: @JamesBond You are correct : any kind of union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$ will only produce open sets.

Consider the the real line with the standard topology. You can check that a basis for this topology is the collection of all open intervals. However, $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ is not an open interval so this set is not an element of the basis. However, it's an element of the topology (as a union of two elements of the basis).

Comment: @JamesBond, the concept of basis is useful because many topologies are most easily defined in terms of a basis which generates them. This is the case for the standard topology on the real line.

Comment: If $B \in \mathcal{B}$, then for all $x \in B$, we have $x \in B$ and $B \subseteq B$, so $B$ is open by the definition of $\mathcal{T}$.

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not a specialist of Set Theory but I think that the Axiom of Regularity doesn't allow things like $\mathcal{B}\in \mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @M.G Different fonts. $B \in \mathcal{B}$, not $\mathcal{B}\in\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: @Daniel, right. Sorry

Comment: @M.G No problem, the fonts are not as different as I would like.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Point (2) guarantees that every intersection of basis sets is a union of basis sets. Thus it's indeed a basis. (I don't like the definition, but it's valid.)

Answer (score 3):

The way you define the open sets in your edited question, it follows that each $B\in\mathcal B$ is open, since for $x\in B$ we have $x\in B$ and $B\subseteq B$.

Answer (score 2):

A basis $\mathcal{B}$ for a topological space X with topology $\mathcal{T}$ **is a collection of open sets in** $\mathcal{T}$ such that every open set in $\mathcal{T}$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$.

Comment: I am looking at a different definition of basis. It is the one that Munkres uses in his book

Comment: I'll have a look. The definition may be different but the concepts behind are the same.

Comment: Have a look to Lemma 13.1 of Munkres' and to the paragraph that follows : "The lemma states that every open set $U$ in $X$ can be expressed as a union of basis elements".

Comment: @JamesBond: If you are using a different definition, could you please edit the question to include it?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I have included the definition that I saw!

Comment: @JamesBond The definition you gave is equivalent to the one given by the answer above.